# Is there some validation in Rails that edits a string before it commits to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an issue when submitting a form in a Rails app. There is no validation on this field in the model.

Here are the Params as they POST to the controller

`"blast"=>{"to"=>"[947363, 947426, 947427, 947432, 947433]"}`

Here is what is what is commited to the DB

`["to", "{\" 947426\",\" 947427\",\" 947432\"}"]`

EDIT:

Controller Code:

```
   def update
      if @blast.update(blast_params)
        redirect_to URI.unescape(params[:ref]) if params[:ref].present?
      end
   end

private 

    def blast_params
      params.require(:blast).permit(:subject, :to, :from_name, :from_email, :body, :json, :name, :active)
    end
```

Model Code:

```
class Blast < ApplicationRecord

end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for Blast.new, url: blasts_create_path, html: {class: "validetta"} do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :subject, value: blast.subject %>
<%= f.hidden_field :from_name, value: blast.from_name %>
<%= f.hidden_field :from_email, value: blast.from_email %>
<%= f.hidden_field :to, value: blast.to %>
<%= f.hidden_field :body, value: blast.body %>
<%= f.hidden_field :json, value: blast.json.to_s %>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.text_field :name, value: "#{blast.name} (copy)", class: "form-control input-lg", data: {'validetta' => 'required'} %>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-success waves-effect waves-light" aria-expanded="false">Next Step <i data-feather="arrow-right-circle" width="15" height="15" style="vertical-align:middle;top:-1px;position:relative;" class="m-l-5"></i></button>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The :to field in the DB:

```
t.text "to", default: [], array: true
```

As you can see, it seems to cut the first and list items from the string. Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: Need more details controller, model code, database name &  field data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was in respect to the serialisation of an array into a string as it is rendered on the DOM and then back into an array as it is passed as a paramater to the controller.

Update the controller as follows:

```
    def create
      blast = @account.blasts.create(blast_params)
      if blast
        if params[:blast][:to].present?
          blast_to_params = params[:blast][:to].gsub('[', '').gsub(']', '').split(',').map{|i| i.to_i}
          blast.update(to: blast_to_params)
        end
        redirect_to blasts_step_1_path(blast)
      else
        redirect_to blasts_path, alert: "Failed to create this blast."
      end
    end
```

Comment: `params[:blast][:to]` is JSON. Parse it with `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

`array: true` says to store the data as a [Postgres array](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array), but `blast_params[:to]` is formatted as [JSON](https://json.org/). Rails is jamming that JSON string in as a Postgres Array and something is getting lost in translation. Plus you're feeding integers to a text column, so it's hung on to the spaces.

```
[1] pry(main)> blast = Blast.new("to"=>"[947363, 947426, 947427, 947432, 947433]")
=> #<Blast:0x00007fa23091ff58
 id: nil,
 to: [" 947426", " 947427", " 947432"],
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
```

You can fix this by first parsing the JSON to a Ruby Array. Then Rails will translate that to a Postgres Array. And you should switch the column type to integer. `t.integer "to", default: [], array: true`.

```
[1] pry(main)> blast = Blast.new("to"=>JSON.parse("[947363, 947426, 947427, 947432, 947433]"))
=> #<Blast:0x00007fa233ad0b38
 id: nil,
 to: [947363, 947426, 947427, 947432, 947433],
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
```

Rather than using a Postgres array, I would suggest storing it as [the more flexible jsonb](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb): `t.jsonb "to", default: []`. You'll still have to parse the incoming JSON, but it will correctly accept a mix of text and integers.